# SSLstrip can capture RDP credentials

Tags: ssl, remote-desktop, https

can a attacker steal my RDP credentials with SSLstrip? I searched on internet and I saw that SSLstrip can steal facebook data by converting https into http. But  windows "remote desktop connection" is secure? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDP has been fairly unsecure since the very beginning.

That said, sslstrip is a tool for MITM attacks, possibly it cannot be used for attacks on RDP.

But there are other tools that can be used for MITM on RDP, like the ones described in this post:

https://labs.portcullis.co.uk/blog/ssl-man-in-the-middle-attacks-on-rdp/